# Custom Keyboard or Soft Keyboard ??? for color change

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to change the color of a soft keyboard(android default) (In the App or outside it )or do I need custom keyboard for that and another thing Can I make the same soft keyboard of the android device but with another language ( changing KEYCODES ???) i guess it will be there a button to change  between the languages but please answer me this two answer it so important ...! sry and thx and how to open the app with different language keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom keyboard with separate Keyboard xml layout file for each supporting language. And `switchToNextInputMethod()` for change between the languages. Look at [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) at first.

**Update:**
Just change `keyboard.xml` to

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:keyWidth="33%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
          android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="Խ" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="Ա" />
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="Ք" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="Ս" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="Տ" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="Ն" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="Ց" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="Գ" />
        <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="Մ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="67" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
             android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
             android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="ԳՒՆ" />
        <Key android:codes="66" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
             android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return"
             android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

in [this](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) example and result is

[image]

Comment: i cant find any example on custom keyboard for another language
and is it possible to change the theme ?? ( another langauges don't have  android:Code= *****)

Comment: and I can't find the source of google keyboard too :( i want same design but more than 24 hours i'm searching there isn't any example or a way for another language like arabic or chinese or frech or ........!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) and [that](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) tutorials.

Comment: it is with their own android:code 55 i guess for number A i want for words like this ԽԱՔՍՏՆՑԳՄԳՒՆ Armenian,arabic or donno another language than english

Comment: Create res/xml/qwerty.xml file for custom locale with:  `<Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="Խ"/>`  etc. values

Comment: But anyway You CAN change appearance and behavior of KeyboardView as You wish. Try [this](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) example as start point (if You use Android Studio You should use File->New->Import project... item to convert it to AS format).